# How to launch an activity containing Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-activity

Hello I am having a login activity in which after successful login I am launching a new activity nextactivity.xml.When I launch this activity it is not going to be successfully launched.Login Activity is still there.When I press the Back button then the nextactivity.xml is launched.
code for nextactivity.xml is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am launching nextactivity.xml with this:

```
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(userid.getText().toString().isEmpty() &&password.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent mainActivityIntent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
                finish();
                onBackPressed();

            }
```

Comment: why you call onBackPressed() after calling finish?? What is its implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using to start another activity on login button click is looking correct.
You need to check if your another activity is starting the login activity again.